# Android Studio Renaming the Project

Tags: android, android-studio

When starting off on this project I did not think much about the name. Now I would like to call it something different, could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: just to be clear not the qualifying package name right

Comment: When I install the app - I would like it to have a different title on the android desktop.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42539444/6296561) the Android Manifest links to a variable in s`strings.xml` called `app_name`.

You should edit the app_name variable and not replace it in the manifest as you can then use the app_name elsewhere in your app and not have to replace it everywhere.

As such, your `strings.xml` should look something like this(looking aside from other added variables):

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Name here</string>
    [other values]
</resources>
```

Simply edit `app_name` to whatever you want to call your app, and reinstall the app. you will now see the new name in place.

**Note:** Editing `app_name` instead of the `android:label`-line in the manifest also updates every reference you may have used it on. The name in a title referenced/linked to the `strings.xml` file-variable `app_name` will also update when you edit it. Changing the line in the manifest and hard-coding it does also work, all though it is better to change the strings.xml-variable

**Second note:**

This will not change your package name or your project name as displayed in Android Studio. These can be changed as well, but it has no effect as to what the device displays. Even though Android Studio shows that it is editing the project "RandomProjectName", the app's name as displayed can be "NameRandomProject". They are not linked together.

Comment: Thanks for this - but still shows old name on Android.

Comment: Try removing the app(uninstall completly), restart the device(delete any cached data) and reinstall

Comment: Also note that the icon on the home window may not update. In that case, a device restart or re-adding the icon is all that is needed. If it shows up without the updated name on the "All apps" list, uninstall restart and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, go to AndroidManifest.xml and change the android:label value. See below,

```
 <application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    **android:label="@string/app_name"**
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Done that - did not change the end install name.

Comment: Can you please share your manifest file and what application name shown in app launcher, and whats your desired name.